# Modifying number of ticks on Pandas hourly time axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas, time-series

If I have the following example Python code using a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

ts = pd.DataFrame(randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000 00:00:00', freq='H', periods=1000), columns=['Data'])
ts['Time'] = ts.index.map(lambda t: t.time())
ts = ts.groupby('Time').mean()
ts.plot(x_compat=True, figsize=(20,10))
```

The output plot is: 
[image]

What is the most elegant way to get the X-Axis ticks to automatically space themselves hourly or bi-hourly? `x_compat=True` has no impact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass to `ts.plot()` the argument `xticks`. Giving the right interval you can plot hourly our bi-hourly like:

```
max_sec = 90000

ts.plot(x_compat=True, figsize=(20,10), xticks=arange(0, max_sec, 3600))

ts.plot(x_compat=True, figsize=(20,10), xticks=arange(0, max_sec, 7200))
```

Here `max_sec` is the maximum value of the `xaxis`, in seconds.

Comment: perhaps you can use `max_sec = (ts.Data.keys()[-1].hour + 1)*3600` to automatically get the maximum value of the `xaxis` in seconds